# Google Merchant throws error “Wrong XML tag"

Tags: xml

I have this XML product file to upload in Google Merchant, I think the problem is related to RSS2.0 specifications or perhaps in combination with encoding. 
The error is on line 17, character 10. So it doesn't like the g:image_​​link tag. Although Google specifies this tag, exactly like this.
I am using a UTF8 (without BOM) character set. But I tried different character sets as well.
Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0">
<channel>
<item>
<g:id>123</g:id>
<title>Title</title>
<link>URL</link>
<description>Description</description>
<g:image_​​link>https://abc....jpg</g:image_​​link>
<g:price>89,00</g:price>
<g:google_​​product_​​category>2534</g:google_​​product_​​category>
<g:condition>New</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:shipping_weight>1.0000</g:shipping_weight>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found problem, although I save it with notepad++ editor in UTF without BOM, there are "invisible" incorrect characters. If I convert the XML text to Ascii I noticed two question marks in front of the underscore: .
Still don't know how they came in there.